# Collections.sort() doesn't work. Problem with implementing the Comparable<> interface

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

Does someone have an idea why this code doesn't sort the employees properly? I need them to be sorted in **ascending order** by the amount of their salary.

> I think I've messed up smth cause I'm storing salaries in doubles. But I really don't know what to do. Plz help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
            new Employee("Steve", 3.1),
            new Employee("Mark", 4.2),
            new Employee("Oliver", 4)));

    System.out.println("Before sorting: " + employees);
    employees.sort(Employee::compareTo);
    System.out.println("After sorting: " + employees);
}

class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    private final String name;
    private final double salary;

    public Employee(String name, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee employee) {
        return (int) this.salary - (int) employee.salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " " + Math.round(salary * 100.0) / 100.0; //2 digits after the dot
    }
}
```

[Outpute:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwISN.png)

[This doesn't work as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksni4.png)

Comment: You are computing the salaries as integers, so `(int) 4.2 - (int) 4 == 0`. Try using `Double#compare(double, double)`.

Comment: You care casting the `salary` to an integer therefor `4.0` and `4.2` have the same value `4`.

Comment: And why doesn't this work?


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee employee) {
        return (int) (this.salary - employee.salary);
    }

Comment: Same reason, `(4.2 - 4.0) == 0.2`, and `(int) 0.2 == 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your `compareTo` function. Both 4.2 and 4.0 are just 4s as integers, so your program doesn't swap them.

You need to compare doubles. I think, [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare-double-double-) will help you.

Comment: Thanks! I used Double.compare() and it worked